# TIdTcpServer connection limiting

Tags: delphi, indy10, tcpserver

I want to restrict the number of incoming connections that a `TIdTcpServer` can take, but the rule I need to apply is a little complex, so I don't think the `MaxConnections` property will work for me.

I have an application running N servers, each using a different protocol on a different port. I need to limit the total number of clients across all N servers. So for example, with 16 servers, and 16 clients allowed, I would allow one client on each, or 16 all on a single server.

It's possible I could manipulate the `MaxConnections` dynamically to fix this (e.g. set them all to zero when I determine we're 'full', and back to 16 or whatever when we're not full, but this feels a little too tricksy.

Is there some kind of virtual `IsConnectionAllowed` method that I can override with my own logic, or a suitable place in the connection process where I can raise an exception if I determine the limit has been exceeded?

Comment: What happens if a client connects, and then never sends data or tries to read from the connection (maybe because the socket was closed on the client side)? I guess there needs a "connection timeout" to protect the server against DOS attacks...

Comment: @mjn It's all internal, and based on persistent connections.

Comment: Why not just create a custom class derived from `TIdTcpServer` that implements the functionality you require? i.e. Implement a `IsConnectionAllowed` method and call that from a modified OnConnect?

Comment: @Andy_D Possibly, but the connection's already made by then. I think in that case I can just make my OnExecute method return immediately.  I'm wondering if there's an easy way to refuse the connection, rather than open it and immediately close it...

Answer (score 1):

Create a new component - TIdTCPServerCollection for example - which is the "owner" of all server components.

In this component, declare a thread-safe property which stores the available - currently unused - connection count.

In the server connect and disconnect logic, decrement / increment this variable, and set MaxConnections to reflect the new limit.

Comment: It turns out this won't work because `MaxConnections=0` means unlimited connections. So if Server 1 has all 16 connections, I can't use `MaxConnections` to prevent other servers from accepting one.

Comment: @Roddy That's how Indy does. A client connects, indy checks if the max number of connections is already reached and based on that disconnects the client. Search "Check MaxConnections" in unit IdCustomTCPServer.

Comment: @ioan You're right. In which case, (because MaxConnections can't block a server with zero current connections) simply returning immediately from the OnExecute event is probably the right approach.

Comment: @Roddy OnExecute is called in a loop for the lifetime of the connection - returning immediately, instead of waiting for available client or server data, will waste CPU resources - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164888/

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to implement a custom `TIdScheduler` class that derives from one of the `TIdSchedulerofThread...` components and override its virtual `AcquireYarn()` method to either:

1. raise an `EAbort` exception if the scheduler's `ActiveYarns` list has reached the max allowed number of connections.  This might cause too tight a loop in `TIdTCPServer` listening threads, though.  To mitigate that, you could put a small timer in the method and only raise the exception if the list remains maxed out for a short period of time.
2. block the calling thread (the `TIdTCPServer` listening thread) until the `ActiveYarns` has fewer yarns than your max connection limit, then call the `inherited` method to return a new `TIdYarn` object normally.

For example:

```
type
  TMyScheduler = class(TIdSchedulerOfThreadDefault)
  public
    function AcquireYarn: TIdYarn; override;
  end;

function TMyScheduler.AcquireYarn: TIdYarn;
begin
  if not ActiveYarns.IsCountLessThan(SomeLimit) then
  begin
    Sleep(1000);
    if not ActiveYarns.IsCountLessThan(SomeLimit) then
      Abort;
  end;
  Result := inherited;
end;
```

Then assign a single instance of this class to the `Scheduler` property of all the servers.  `TIdTCPServer` calls `AcquireYarn()` before accepting a new client connection.

Another option, for Windows only, would be to derive a new `TIdStack` class from `TIdStackWindows`  and override its virtual `Accept()` method to use Winsock's [`WSAAccept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead of its `accept()` function.  `WSAAccept()` allows you to assign a callback function that decides whether a new client is accepted or rejected based on criteria passed to the callback (QOS, etc).  That callback could check a global counter you maintain for how many active connections are running (or just sum up all of the servers' active `Contexts` counts), and then return `CF_REJECT` if the limit has been reached, otherwise return `CF_ACCEPT`.  You could then use the `SetStackClass()` function in the `IdStack` unit to assign your class as the active Stack for all Indy socket connections.

For example:

```
type
  TMyStack = class(TIdStackWindows)
  public
    function Accept(ASocket: TIdStackSocketHandle; var VIP: string; var VPort: TIdPort; var VIPVersion: TIdIPVersion): TIdStackSocketHandle; override;
  end;

function MyAcceptCallback(lpCallerId: LPWSABUF; lpCallerData: LPWSABUF; lpSQOS, pGQOS: LPQOS; lpCalleeId, lpCalleeData: LPWSABUF; g: PGROUP; dwCallbackData: DWORD_PTR): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  if NumActiveConnections >= SomeLimit then
    Result := CF_REJECT
  else
    Result := CF_ACCEPT;
end;

function TMyStack.Accept(ASocket: TIdStackSocketHandle; var VIP: string; var VPort: TIdPort; var VIPVersion: TIdIPVersion): TIdStackSocketHandle;
var
  LSize: Integer;
  LAddr: SOCKADDR_STORAGE;
begin
  LSize := SizeOf(LAddr);
  //Result := IdWinsock2.accept(ASocket, IdWinsock2.PSOCKADDR(@LAddr), @LSize);
  Result := IdWinsock2.WSAAccept(ASocket, IdWinsock2.PSOCKADDR(@LAddr), @LSize, @MyAcceptCallback, 0);
  if Result <> INVALID_SOCKET then begin
    case LAddr.ss_family of
      Id_PF_INET4: begin
        VIP := TranslateTInAddrToString(PSockAddrIn(@LAddr)^.sin_addr, Id_IPv4);
        VPort := ntohs(PSockAddrIn(@LAddr)^.sin_port);
        VIPVersion := Id_IPv4;
      end;
      Id_PF_INET6: begin
        VIP := TranslateTInAddrToString(PSockAddrIn6(@LAddr)^.sin6_addr, Id_IPv6);
        VPort := ntohs(PSockAddrIn6(@LAddr)^.sin6_port);
        VIPVersion := Id_IPv6;
      end;
      else begin
        CloseSocket(Result);
        Result := INVALID_SOCKET;
        IPVersionUnsupported;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

initialization
  SetStackClass(TMyStack);
```

This way, Indy will never see any rejected client connections at all, and you do not have to worry about implementing any other hacks inside of `TIdTCPServer` or its various dependencies.  Everything will work normally and simply block as expected whenever `TIdStack.Accept()` does not return an accepted client.